# How to read barcode on NADRA NIC?

Tags: barcode

I am writing an application which reads barcode from NIC issued by NADRA (http://www.nadra.gov.pk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=9). NADRA issues CNIC to citizens of Pakistan. I want to read these barcode which are printed on CNIC. NADRA has encoded information like, Name, Father Name, Address, DOB etc, but these informations are stored in Urdu. I am successful in reading these Barcodes, but the thing is that, I cannot convert their characterset to Urdu. I installed urdu fonts, like Noori Nistalique, Aswad and many more, but these characterset just shows a jumble of characters, not a meaningful information. when i decode these barcode in simple english, it shows the numeric information correct, but does not show the information which is in urdu.

Have anyone tried to read these barcodes, and successfully decoded it? please help me, or guide me what I have to do...?

here is a sample which i read, this is in simple english:

> A0U1200708091232 13501722 T31 2602
>   -E'/

here is a sample which i read and this is in Urdu:

> آڑم٠٢٨٧٨٧٠١٨٠ء١٢٠٠٧٠٨٠٩١٢٣٢ ١٣٥٠١٧٢٢ ٹ٣١ص ٢٦٠٢
>   -فؓف ؐف-فڈف┴ف ‌،ف٩ف┴ف ‌١ف-فؐف"ففف  ‌ ‌
>   ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌

as you can see, numeric information is same but the information which is encoded in urdu is jumbled...

any help???

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?? if so please share

Comment: moonzai can you please help i am unable to find any library to read PDF417...using zxing right now....kindly guide me.....

Comment: zxing is good library, and it has support for PDF417. You need better camera for that, atleast 8MP, then you will be able to read PDF417 on Mobile Phone. There is another library, ZBar, its written in C/C++. You can also use this library. But these two libraries depend upon good Camera Resulotion.

Comment: @moonzai, @ KhaledJaveed - The qrcode of cnic just gives the cnic number. How did guys extracted the other details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NADRA did a trick, NADRA is actually using last two characters form Hex value of a word e.g. if `\u0622` is Alif (suppose) then NADRA is using only the last two characters for encoding, `22` so this is the trick only. I am attaching some code that will convert hex to Urdu, read barcode data, convert it to hex string, and then pass this string to this function, you will get all information in Urdu, just put this string in some Urdu or Arabic supported View (Android), Component (Java) or if you are using C# then put it in a Label.

```
public class ConvertToUrdu {

public static String convertToUrdu(String text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] characters = text.split(",");

    for(String character : characters)
    {


        //if (ListDigits.Contains(ch))
        //{
        //    continue;
        //}
        switch (character)
        {
            case "20":
                sb.append(" ");
                break;

            case "22":
                sb.append("\u0622");
                break;

            case "27":
                sb.append("\u0627");
                break;

            case "13":
                sb.append("\u0613");
                break;

            case "28":
                sb.append("\u0628");
                break;

            case "2B":
                sb.append("\u062b");
                break;

            case "86":
                sb.append("\u0686");
                break;

            case "88":
                sb.append("\u0688");
                break;

            case "2F":
                sb.append("\u062f");
                break;

            case "10":
                sb.append("\u0610");
                break;

            case "39":
                sb.append("\u0639");
                break;

            case "41":
                sb.append("\u0641");
                break;

            case "3A":
                sb.append("\u063a");
                break;

            case "AF":
                sb.append("\u06af");
                break;

            case "2D":
                sb.append("\u062d");
                break;

            case "BE":
                sb.append("\u06be");
                break;

            case "CC":
                sb.append("\u06cc");
                break;

            case "36":
                sb.append("\u0636");
                break;

            case "2C":
                sb.append("\u062c");
                break;

            case "2E":
                sb.append("\u062e");
                break;

            case "43":
                sb.append("\u0643");
                break;

            case "12":
                sb.append("\u0612");
                break;

            case "44":
                sb.append("\u0644");
                break;

            case "45":
                sb.append("\u0645");
                break;

            case "BA":
                sb.append("\u06ba");
                break;

            case "46":
                sb.append("\u0646");
                break;

            case "29":
                sb.append("\u0629");
                break;

            case "A9":
                sb.append("\u06a9");
                break;

            case "C1":
                sb.append("\u06c1");
                break;

            //case "45":
            //    sb.Append("\u0645");
            //    break;

            case "7E":
                sb.append("\u067e");
                break;

            case "42":
                sb.append("\u0642");
                break;

            case "91":
                sb.append("\u0691");
                break;

            case "31":
                sb.append("\u0631");
                break;

            case "35":
                sb.append("\u0635");
                break;

            case "33":
                sb.append("\u0633");
                break;

            case "79":
                sb.append("\u0679");
                break;

            case "2A":
                sb.append("\u062a");
                break;

            case "21":
                sb.append("\u0621");
                break;

            case "38":
                sb.append("\u0638");
                break;

            case "37":
                sb.append("\u0637");
                break;

            //case "48":
            //    sb.Append("\\u0635\u0644\u0649\u0020\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u0020\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0647\u0020\u0648\u0633\u0644\u0645");
            //    break;

            case "48":
                sb.append("\u0648");
                break;

            case "98":
                sb.append("\u0698");
                break;

            case "34":
                sb.append("\u0634");
                break;

            case "D2":
                sb.append("\u06d2");
                break;

            case "30":
                sb.append("\u0630");
                break;

            case "32":
                sb.append("\u0632");
                break;

            case "60":
                sb.append("\u0660");
                break;

            case "61":
                sb.append("\u0661");
                break;

            case "62":
                sb.append("\u0662");
                break;

            case "63":
                sb.append("\u0663");
                break;

            case "64":
                sb.append("\u0664");
                break;

            case "65":
                sb.append("\u0665");
                break;

            case "66":
                sb.append("\u0666");
                break;

            case "67":
                sb.append("\u0667");
                break;

            case "68":
                sb.append("\u0668");
                break;

            case "69":
                sb.append("\u0669");
                break;

            case "0C":
                sb.append(" \u200c");
                break;

            case "D4":
                sb.append("\u06d4");
                break;

            //case "0C":
            //    sb.Append("\u060c");
            //    break;

            case "1F":
                sb.append("\u061f");
                break;

            case "02":
                sb.append("\u0602");
                break;

            case "1B":
                sb.append("\u061b");
                break;

            case "7b":
                sb.append("\u007b");
                break;

            case "7D":
                sb.append("\u007d");
                break;
            //default:
            //    sb.Append(ch);
            //    break;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

I wrote this code for Java, you can convert it for any other language.

Hope for the Best :-)

**NOTE**
For my convenience, I added ',' after two characters in original String, so e.g.  `A0U1200708091232` -> `A0,U1,20,07,08,09,12,32`. just for debugging, so this function actually converting second string to Urdu.

**EDIT**
As from the comments, here is my function which is converting string to hex, I wrote this in C#

```
private string convertToHex(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                sb.Append('\n');
                sb.Append(',');
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X}", (int)c));
                sb.Append(',');
                //sb.Append((int)c + " ");
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

In JAVA you can convert by writing `String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) c);`

Comment: Thank you dear for your help! You for sure saved a lot of my time. I will give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: I have followed your footsteps and have extracted most out of it, but still some characters are missing; like it prints "جاوید" as "جاود" i.e skips "yey" and how to determine if a english character comes in the string...
If you are not bothered, can we talk on this??

Comment: I faced these problems also, check hex of "yey", and change that hex in above function. It may change other alphabets also, you need to make your application more intelligent for handling these kind of confusions.

Comment: Yup! thanks for writing back. I have came to conclusion that my scanner is missing some characters to read properly, coz an online scanner (http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx) and an app on my moblie scanned all characters.
For sake of my interest, can you share details of your work? You may contact me (if you want to) on my mail khaled.javeed@gmail.com [I hope I am not violating any rules of this site by sharing my personal ID :P]

Comment: I am receiving this string AE71145350170U1200108031246 611011805606102 X41G61 23111977 (D 'DE - EH / (Y 0 H' DAB '1 E - EH / (Y E ©' فلمیں ایف ایف ای (1 351-C ¯ D I / E - ڈی Á 483 I © Y 1 G-6 / 1-4 '3 D' E '(' / '3 D' E '(' /  

I can change it to HEX value but not in urdu. Any help?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, make pairs of this whole string like, AE, 71, 14 and so on, then pass this string to the function I wrote above. This function will convert all those 2 value hex to complete Urdu Character's hex. Then show the result in any Urdu supported TextBox, EditText or anything.

Comment: Can you please share the code to convert to Hex? My code is giving incorrect hex.

Comment: Show me your HEX for urdu.

Comment: here is HEX urdu line  35 6 3a 6 cc 6 b1 6 a0 39 6 44 6 cc 6 a0 b4 6 27 6 141 6

Comment: How are you reading barcode, Through phone, or with some scanner, I think the scanner you have is reading barcode in different character set.

Comment: I am reading bar code using Android phone i.e Nexus 5. I am interfacing my app with Bar code scanner app which returns me above string. I convert this string to hex and then pass them to your above code

Comment: @moonzai I am having issue with Address cause address contain ENG+ URDU + numeric how u distinguishes them cause when i convert it its showing name and father name is okay but address got change where english or numeric character use

Comment: @moonzai yes please can we come chat ? i got two different format one for  2010 earlier NIC and after 2014 both little different i will share with can we come on chat?

Comment: "AF20715300060U1200111211952
103731043808002
4210116286091
O3F7S1
1983-02-25
E-E/9D .'F
F,E 'D-3F .'F
'1HF 1'&D 3y A2 3ADy FE(1 P-301E-D D3*'F ,H1
(D' 171' 41B

                                                                                                                                                      
" this nic generated on 2014 and nic number at row 3

Comment: @moonzai "AJJ0461160180U1200708201152
421014692139100
JK3J4T
20101988
4' 2( 81 '-E/
81 '-E/
E'F FE(1 L-343E-D F'1* 1'3y1 21'
*-5D H 6D9  1' H37
1'
                                                                                                                                                         
" and this one earlier 2010 and nice number at row 2

Comment: I simplified your code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZxcmC2 - I think NADRA cannot decrypt the Address with english and urdu both characters. This algo cannot distinguish between E or م (meem) e.g.: مکان نمبر E-111. There is another problem NADRA omits comma therefore you cannot distinguish the spaces e.g: کراجی،سندھ will become کراچیسندھ ...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of @moonzai above, I would like to add some detail that I have so far able to achieve (with help of @moonzai's post off-course!).

So far, there are three types of CNIC:

1. Regular CNIC [BarCode Encoding: PDF417]
2. NICOP Card [BarCode Encoding: Code 128]
3. Card with DIP Chip [BarCode Encoding: QR Code]

The latter two (2 & 3) only have ID card number and a few additional numeric details (most probably number of issues in case of (2) and Nadra_DB_# in (3))
Here is the information encoded in the PDF417 format barcode (1):

- Receipt number (Parchi Number) which includes timestamp of your visit
  to NADRA’s office
- CNIC Number
- Family Number (Khandan Number)
- Date of Birth
- Full Name [Urdu]
- Father’s Name [Urdu]
- Full Address with District and Tehsil information [Urdu + English + Eng-Numeric]

The urdu is encoded by ommitting the common part of HEX code i.e. \u06 in case of Java/C/C++/... and "&#x6" in-case of Web or simply 0x06.
e.g. HEX code for "alif" is \u0627 or ا they only added 27 and omitted &#x6.
In case of word "جاوید" the actual string should look like: &#x62C&#x627&#x648&#x6CC&#x62F
but NADRA added only: 2C2748CC2F *(ommitting all &#x6)* 
Appended below is a VBA code that helps generate a WEB string for scanned output of CNIC card
I will keep on adding refined code, aswell as codes in other languages; especially in JS/ Jquery and PHP.

```
Public Function Convert2Urdu(vString As String) As String
    Dim vCharArray As Variant, vChar As String

    For i = 1 To Len(vString)
        vChar = Mid(vString, i, 1)
        vCharArray = vCharArray & GetUrduChar(Hex(AscW(vChar)))
    Next
    Convert2Urdu = vCharArray
End Function

Private Function GetUrduChar(vHex) As String
    Select Case vHex
        ' Alphabets
        Case "22", "27", "28", "7E", "2A", "79", "2B", "2C", "86", "2D", "2E", "2F", "88", "30", "31", "91", "32", "98", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3A", "41", "42", "A9", "AF", "44", "45", "46", "BA", "48", "C1", "C3", "BE", "21", "CC", "D2"
            GetUrduChar = "" & vHex
        ' Numerics
        Case "F0", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9"
            GetUrduChar = "" & vHex
        ' Eraabs
        Case "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "56", "57", "58", "70"
            GetUrduChar = "" & vHex
        ' Punctuation
        Case "1B", "1F", "64", "6C", "D4", "6B"
            GetUrduChar = "" & vHex
        ' Space
        Case "20"
            GetUrduChar = "&#x" & "0" & vHex
        Case Else
           GetUrduChar = " " & Chr(vHex) & " " ' Ideally, it should be Chr(Asc(Hex)) [working on it]
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I am receiving this string AE71145350170U1200108031246 611011805606102 X41G61 23111977 (D 'DE - EH / (Y 0 H' DAB '1 E - EH / (Y E ©' فلمیں ایف ایف ای (1 351-C ¯ D I / E - ڈی Á 483 I © Y 1 G-6 / 1-4 '3 D' E '(' / '3 D' E '(' /  

I can change it to HEX value but not in urdu. Any help?

Comment: can u guys guide me, which library you guys are using for PDF417...i am stuck kindly help !!! i will be really grateful !

Comment: Which PHP library to use?