# How to read NADRA NIC barcode?

Tags: python, extract, qr-code, scanning, urdu

I want to read bar codes of NIC issued by NADRA using PYTHON. But, the QR Code does not extracts any information of the card. If someone working or has worked on this project, please guide me how can I extract the information( English + Urdu ).

Regards!

I tried to scan the QR Code with a python script but it not does not give information even in English, too. I need both Urdu and English text.

Comment: Could you give an example of the code ? Is the code like [this example](https://nadra-online.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/poc-img.jpg) ? Often codes only return numbers, as an ID, and without a reader connected to a data storage behind, it's of no value to you. Example: Reading `78000003696972434210783531` could mean anything: a unique tag, a personal Pakistan ID, random dice rolls, a binary file..   So: give example(s).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Some background info, and Java and  C++ code that could be adapted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472824/how-to-read-barcode-on-nadra-nic